# Excel - Tabelas - Identificando a próxima linha

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

boa tarde. Essa é minha primeira pergunta por aqui. Desde já, agradeço a quem puder me orientar.

Fiz uma planilha com algumas tabelas (aba "Página Inicial", "Formatar como tabela"). Depois, fiz um VBA para limpar essa tabela e inserir novas informações a partir de um arquivo texto. Eu estava utilizando um recurso que é identificar a linha onde está a tabela através do comando Range("Nome da tabela").row. A partir daí, eu incrementava um contador que ia sempre me dando o número da próxima linha. Vejam abaixo:

```
    ...
    Application.Goto Reference:="NomeDaTabela"
    PróximaLinhaDaTabela = Range("NomeDaTabela").Row
    For X = 1 To 50 'Simulando os registros de um array
        ActiveSheet.Cells(PróximaLinhaDaTabela, 1) = X
        PróximaLinhaDaTabela = PróximaLinhaDaTabela + 1
    Next
    ...
```

Acontece que eu, de fato, não estou "controlando" a próxima linha da tabela "NomeDaTabela". Estou controlando a próxima linha da planilha ("ActiveSheet"). Quando eu tento adicionar uma nova linha na tabela através do comando Range("Nome da tabela).Insert, ele insere uma linha no início da tabela, logo abaixo do cabeçalho. Eu gostaria que ele inserisse ao final, após as outras linhas da tabela que já estejam preenchidas. E que eu conseguisse referenciar essa nova linha para adicionar valores. Se eu tento utilizar o comando Range("NomeDaTabela").Cells(PróximaLinhaDaTabela, Coluna), ele utiliza a posição da tabela mais o número de linhas informado. Ou seja, o comando Range("NomeDaTabela") "sabe" onde está localizada a tabela. Eu é que não sei como referenciar.

Alguém já fez algo do tipo?

Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seja bem vindo!

Se estiver procurando como adicionar uma linha em um objeto como uma tabela pré definida o código será algo assim:

```
Set myNewRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObject(1).ListRows.Add
```

Neste caso deve adicionar uma linha abaixo.

Espero ter ajudado!

[Referência](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196248.aspx)

Comment: Obrigado, Evert. Era exatamente o que eu estava procurando. Fiz umas pesquisas e já vi que vou ter que alterar meu código pra tratar adequadamente essas tabelas. Eu estava usando "Range", mas acho que devo tratar como "ListObject". Obrigado pela ajuda.